# Deploying a self signed ceritificates in an Azure webapp

Tags: azure

I have created a webapp in Azure and deployed few webapi 2 services. It is not a cloud service. No web and worker roles involved. No public domain name is attached to it. Also I don't want to use the default Microsoft certificate. Is it possible to install a self signed certificate to that webapp to enable https?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you can use a "cloudapp.net" domain for this, but only for test purposes as Microsoft documentation explains:

> For test purposes, you can create and use a self-signed certificate. A
>   self-signed certificate is not authenticated through a CA and can use
>   the cloudapp.net domain as the website URL. For example, the task
>   below uses a self-signed certificate in which the common name (CN)
>   used in the certificate is sslexample.cloudapp.net.

reference: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate/

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I was already able to deploy a self-signed certificate for a cloud service site (subdomain.cloudapp.net). But it is not possible for web app sites(subdomain.azurewebsites.net) site.

Comment: I think that you can only use "subdomain.cloudapp.net" with self signed certificates, otherwise you should use a CA generated certificate to azure.

Comment: A public domain name needs to be associated with  the "subdomain.azurewebsites.net" before deploying self-signed or CA generated certificate. Without associating a public domain, SSL cannot be deployed in "azurewebsites.net" domain. Reference: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/